# call Add specific Product to Cart and go to cart on phtml Static Template

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, addtocart

Is there a way to Add a Specific product by ID on a phtml file on a click event and then go to the cart ?
I need this because i have a custom designed product page for a subscription product with 3 different discounts. so that you can add 1 of 3 different products to cart on this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an 'Add to Cart' button in your`.phtml` file like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('checkout/cart/add') ?>" method="post">
    <input
        name="form_key"
        type="hidden"
        value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormKey(); ?>"/>
    <input
        name="return_url"
        type="hidden"
        value="<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getCartUrl() ?>"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="5"/> <!-- Product ID goes here -->

    <button type="submit">Add To Cart</button>
</form>
```

Clicking the button will add the product of specified ID and redirect to the cart.

Comment: when i replace the 5 with a 1 where 1 is the product id i get on click redirected to the cart but actulay it doesnt add the product to the cart. is there maybe anything missing ?

Comment: Are there configuration options for the product, or is it a basic product?

Comment: its a basic product

Comment: Check that the product is enabled and in stock. I tested the code with a simple product and it works.

Comment: it is enabled and in stock. i can see it in the catalog. Maybe the issue is how i call the block in the layout. i remember im magento 1.* i had sometimes issues with blocks and permissions of the block. could that be the issue ?

Comment: This is how i call the block:         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="home-box" template="Magento_Theme::unsereboxen.phtml">

Comment: I don't think the block call is the problem. Are you able to add the product to cart from the actual product page? Try it with the `return_url` input removed and there should be a message that may help diagnose the problem.

Comment: thanks for your help Allen. i found out that the problem is that im calling it from a Product Site where i updated the Layout. When i add this to a CMS Page it works. Is there any way to disable the default Add to Cart button from the old product page layout  ? i would like to use a layout updated product page instead of a CMS page for it.